# How to handle various notify on main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I'm currently developing some classes based on `Thread` and using `wait` and `notify`, and I have a question on how to handle it when more than one `wait` is triggered.

I have this method

```
private void fillBlocks(){
    ASCIIDataStream    ads = new ASCIIDataStream(this.getRawCode());
    ASCIIDataStream    aux = new ASCIIDataStream("");
    DataStream<?, ?>[] bds = null;

    if((ads.getProcessedChars() < this.BLOCK_LENGTH) && (!ads.isDone())){
        try{
            ads.wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    bds = this.divide(ads, this.BLOCK_LENGTH, Balance.LEFT, Format.BIN);
    this.blocks.add(bds[0]);

    this.notify();
    aux = (ASCIIDataStream)bds[1];

    do{         
        bds = this.divide(aux, this.BLOCK_LENGTH, Balance.LEFT, Format.BIN);
        this.blocks.add(bds[0]);
        aux = (ASCIIDataStream)bds[1];
    }while(bds[1] instanceof DataStream<?, ?>);
}
```

And the method from `ads` that trigger the `notify`:

```
private synchronized boolean feed(Character c){
    if(super.addOutput(c))
        this.processedChars++;
    else
        return false;

    if((this.processedChars % this.threshold == 0) && (this.processedChars > 0))
        this.notify();

    return true;
}
```

So, to sum up, `ads` makes some data blocks based on a input, and the main class needs to `wait` until a block is done, so I need to put some `wait` on the `do` block...

```
    do{         
        bds = this.divide(aux, this.BLOCK_LENGTH, Balance.LEFT, Format.BIN);
        this.blocks.add(bds[0]);
        aux = (ASCIIDataStream)bds[1];
        //make some waiting here
    }while(bds[1] instanceof DataStream<?, ?>);
```

So, my question is, if `ads` triggers (for example) two `notify` while the main class still didn't reach the `wait` part, it will be two "notifications" in a kind of stack, or I will lose some "notifications"?

Hope this is clear enough, I'm a quite new on this methods and it's a bit hard for me.

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like a standard producer/consumer problem. Why not use a blocking queue instead of using the (too) low level wait/notify methods?

Comment: @assylias (don't get me wrong) I'm not using it because I didn't know from it's existence until now... Is there any standard class that helps to implement such thing? Or maybe creating a sync list in which the classes do some pull/push? --- OK nevermind, I already googled it and there are some standar classes. I will look forward to this topic!